# What algorithms could I use to identify content on a web page

Tags: algorithm, html, html-content-extraction

I have a web page loaded up in the browser (i.e. its DOM and element positioning are both accessible to me) and I want to find the block element (or a sorted list of these elements), which likely contains the most content (as in a continuous block of text). The goal is to exclude things like menus, headers, footers and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my personal favorite: [VIPS: a Vision-based Page Segmentation Algorithm](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=70027)

Answer (score 2):

First, if you need to parse a web page, I would use [HTMLAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)  to transform it to an XML. It will speed everything and will enable you, using a simple XPath to go directly to the BODY.

After that, you have to run on all the divs (You can get all the DIV elements in a list from the agility pack), and get whatever you want.

Comment: I'm interested more in the kinds of criteria I could possibly use to judge the individual candidate nodes.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple technique to do this,based on analysing how "noisy" HTML is, i.e., what is the ratio of markup to displayed text through an html page.  [The Easy Way to Extract Useful Text from Arbitrary HTML](http://ai-depot.com/articles/the-easy-way-to-extract-useful-text-from-arbitrary-html/) describes this tex, giving some python code to illustrate.

Cf. also the [HTML::ContentExtractor](http://search.cpan.org/~jzhang/HTML-ContentExtractor-0.02/lib/HTML/ContentExtractor.pm) Perl module, which implements this idea.  It would make sense to clean the html first, if you wanted to use this, using beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Vit Baisa's thesis on [Web Content Cleaning](http://is.muni.cz/th/139654/fi_m/thesis.pdf), I think he has some code too, but I can't find a link for it. There is also a [discussion](https://web.archive.org/web/20100109110648/http://lingpipe-blog.com/2010/01/06/blegging-for-help-web-scraping-for-content/) of the very same problem on the natural language processing LingPipe blog.